# unmanagedSources not in compile inspected tree in sbt

Tags: sbt

Today I was playing with sbt (`1.0.2`); Inspecting **compile** task dependency tree (using `inspect tree compile`), anticipating to find its trace to **unmanagedSourceDirectories** setting but it was not there.

The tree seemed to be trimmed because on one of its leaves I could find the task **sources** which if you inspect its tree you'd find **unmanagedSourceDirectories**.

Now my question is what exactly limits `inspect tree` output ? I speculated maybe it's max depth but there were already leaves deeper than **sources** depth level on tree of `compile` task.
And how can I get **full dependency tree** for a task ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one hour of debugging I figured compile task as in `compile in (ThisProject, Compile)` specifically depends on `sources in (ThisProject, Compile, compile)` and `sources` does not have any value at this exact scope, therefore tree-traversal does not continue and makes this a leaf.

However, in terms of finding value for `sources in (ThisProject, Compile, compile)` when sbt does not find value for the key `sources` in this exact scope, it goes into fallback mode and value searching will [delegated to more general scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scope-Delegation.html#Scope+delegation+rules).

Which in our case there is a value in the scope `sources in (ThisProject, Compile, *)`. You can find a whole dependency tree for this one that traces back to `unmanagedSourceDirectories` setting.

**Conclusion:** `inspect tree` does not take dependencies of *scope-delegatee*s into account.

Comment: Now, how can we `inspect tree` with scope-delegatees taken into account as well ?